# My robot keeps getting saved as one cylinder leaving out the bottom cube

Tags: gazebo, joint, robot-model

I created a robot in the model editor that is made up of a cube and a cylinder with a revolute joint between them but after saving it and inserting another instance into the world, I only get the cylinder and no cube at the bottom. There is a revolute joint between the two so I don't get how the two don't move together or get bundled up. What is happening with gazebo?

Using:

- Ubuntu 18.06
- gazebo9

---

**EDIT:**

Here's `myrobot.sdf`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name='myrobot'>
    <link name='link_0'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.166667</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.166667</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.166667</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 -0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>1 1 1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='vertex'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
        </material>
        <transparency>0</transparency>
        <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
        <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>1 1 1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
            <torsional>
              <coefficient>1</coefficient>
              <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
              <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
              <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
              <ode>
                <slip>0</slip>
              </ode>
            </torsional>
          </friction>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
            <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
            <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
            <ode>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
              <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0</min_depth>
            </ode>
            <bullet>
              <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
              <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
            </bullet>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <link name='link_1'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.145833</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.145833</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.125</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.2</radius>
            <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='vertex'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
        </material>
        <transparency>0</transparency>
        <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
        <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.2</radius>
            <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
            <torsional>
              <coefficient>1</coefficient>
              <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
              <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
              <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
              <ode>
                <slip>0</slip>
              </ode>
            </torsional>
          </friction>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
            <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
            <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
            <ode>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
              <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0</min_depth>
            </ode>
            <bullet>
              <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
              <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
            </bullet>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name='link_0_JOINT_0' type='revolute'>
      <parent>link_0</parent>
      <child>link_1</child>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        <use_parent_model_frame>0</use_parent_model_frame>
        <limit>
          <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>
          <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>
          <effort>-1</effort>
          <velocity>-1</velocity>
        </limit>
        <dynamics>
          <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
          <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
          <damping>0</damping>
        </dynamics>
      </axis>
      <physics>
        <ode>
          <limit>
            <cfm>0</cfm>
            <erp>0.2</erp>
          </limit>
          <suspension>
            <cfm>0</cfm>
            <erp>0.2</erp>
          </suspension>
        </ode>
      </physics>
    </joint>
    <static>0</static>
    <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Updated `myrobot.sdf` that shows up upside-down.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name='robot'>
    <link name='link_0'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.166667</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.166667</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.166667</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 1.0 0 0 0</pose>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>1 1 1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='vertex'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
        </material>
        <transparency>0</transparency>
        <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
        <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>1 1 1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
            <torsional>
              <coefficient>1</coefficient>
              <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
              <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
              <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
              <ode>
                <slip>0</slip>
              </ode>
            </torsional>
          </friction>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
            <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
            <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
            <ode>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
              <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0</min_depth>
            </ode>
            <bullet>
              <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
              <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
            </bullet>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <link name='link_1'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.145833</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.145833</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.125</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <pose frame=''>-1e-06 0 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.2</radius>
            <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='vertex'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
        </material>
        <transparency>0</transparency>
        <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
        <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.2</radius>
            <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
            <torsional>
              <coefficient>1</coefficient>
              <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
              <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
              <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
              <ode>
                <slip>0</slip>
              </ode>
            </torsional>
          </friction>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
            <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
            <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
            <ode>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
              <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0</min_depth>
            </ode>
            <bullet>
              <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
              <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
            </bullet>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name='link_0_JOINT_1' type='revolute'>
      <parent>link_0</parent>
      <child>link_1</child>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 -0.04 0 0</pose>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        <use_parent_model_frame>0</use_parent_model_frame>
        <limit>
          <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>
          <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>
          <effort>-1</effort>
          <velocity>-1</velocity>
        </limit>
        <dynamics>
          <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
          <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
          <damping>0</damping>
        </dynamics>
      </axis>
      <physics>
        <ode>
          <limit>
            <cfm>0</cfm>
            <erp>0.2</erp>
          </limit>
          <suspension>
            <cfm>0</cfm>
            <erp>0.2</erp>
          </suspension>
        </ode>
      </physics>
    </joint>
    <static>0</static>
    <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Comment: Can you share the saved file?

Comment: @xperroni, I added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that what you're seeing when you add your robot model to the world is something like this:

[image: Top robot part]

That is, only the top part of the robot is visible. The problem is not that the bottom part isn't there, it's just that the robot's origin is the joint between the two parts, therefore the lower part is below the floor. If you rotate the world (hold `<Shift> + <Left Mouse Click>` then move the mouse around) so you can see it from under the floor, you'll probably see something like this:

[image]

You have two ways to fix this. Either you keep the model as it is, and manually add a vertical offset to its pose when adding it to a world:

[image]

Or you add a vertical offset to the `model.sdf` file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name='myrobot'>
    <!-- This shifts the entire model 1.0 m up. -->
    <pose frame=''>0 0 1.0 0 0 0</pose>

    <link name='link_0'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.166667</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.166667</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.166667</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 -0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>1 1 1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='vertex'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
        </material>
        <transparency>0</transparency>
        <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
        <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>1 1 1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
            <torsional>
              <coefficient>1</coefficient>
              <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
              <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
              <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
              <ode>
                <slip>0</slip>
              </ode>
            </torsional>
          </friction>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
            <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
            <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
            <ode>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
              <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0</min_depth>
            </ode>
            <bullet>
              <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
              <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
            </bullet>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <link name='link_1'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.145833</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.145833</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.125</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.2</radius>
            <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='vertex'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
        </material>
        <transparency>0</transparency>
        <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
        <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.2</radius>
            <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
            <torsional>
              <coefficient>1</coefficient>
              <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
              <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
              <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
              <ode>
                <slip>0</slip>
              </ode>
            </torsional>
          </friction>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
            <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
            <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
            <ode>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
              <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0</min_depth>
            </ode>
            <bullet>
              <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
              <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
            </bullet>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name='link_0_JOINT_0' type='revolute'>
      <parent>link_0</parent>
      <child>link_1</child>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        <use_parent_model_frame>0</use_parent_model_frame>
        <limit>
          <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>
          <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>
          <effort>-1</effort>
          <velocity>-1</velocity>
        </limit>
        <dynamics>
          <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
          <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
          <damping>0</damping>
        </dynamics>
      </axis>
      <physics>
        <ode>
          <limit>
            <cfm>0</cfm>
            <erp>0.2</erp>
          </limit>
          <suspension>
            <cfm>0</cfm>
            <erp>0.2</erp>
          </suspension>
        </ode>
      </physics>
    </joint>
    <static>0</static>
    <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

In the latter case the robot model's bottom will be automatically aligned with the floor when you add it.

Comment: The variables in `model.sdf` file for `<pose>` are the same ones in the GUI, right?

Comment: For some reason, I am getting an inverted robot.

Comment: Yes, the order of parameters is `<pose>x y z roll pitch yaw</pose>`, same as the GUI. Setting a position offset shouldn't invert anything, can you share your updated model?

Comment: the updated model is at the end of the question.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. You changed the pose of `link_0` from `<pose frame=''>0 0 -0.5 0 -0 0</pose>` to `<pose frame=''>0 0 1.0 0 -0 0</pose>`, but what you really needed to do was to _add_ a `<pose frame=''>0 0 1.0 0 -0 0</pose>` right under the `<model>` tag, above the first `<link>` tag. I'll update my answer to make this point clearer.

Comment: I was able to get the model to show upright the way I wanted it. Could you help clarify/explain why my first change led to an inversion?

Comment: It wasn't that it was inverted, but when you changed the pose of `link_0` from `<pose frame=''>0 0 -0.5 0 -0 0</pose>` to `<pose frame=''>0 0 1.0 0 -0 0</pose>`, you effectively placed it above `link_1`.

Comment: Haha. What a coincidence!!